# Highcharts tooltip formatter using jquery replace

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I haven't found a way to replace commas with line breaks `<br>` from within tooltip formatter.

I want to be able to pass this data in:

```
var data = [     
    { "hc-key": "ad", "code": ['dogs','cats','horses','birds','snakes','boar'] }
    ];
```

And use split/join or replace in the formatter like so:

```
        tooltip: {
            backgroundColor: 'none',
            borderWidth: 0,
            shadow: false,
            useHTML: true,
            padding: 0,
        formatter:function(){
            $('#tooltip').html(this.point.code).replace(/,/g,'<br>');
        }
        },
```

Any ideas how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return the string that you want as the tooltip, and use join:

http://jsfiddle.net/rL5ju28j/

```
tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
        return this.point.code.join(',').replace(/,/g,'<br>');
    }
}
```

http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/tooltip#formatter